# Are these two ways to solution of inequality both correct

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

Are these two ways of completing this inequality both correct: (First one is from proffesor, and second one I did, the answer is at the end correct, but I cant figure out if my number of solutions matches because of some wild luck or is that also an correct way for the solution)
**First:**
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \left|\frac{2-5 x}{2 x+1}\right| \leq 2, D . P .: 2 x+1 \neq 0 \Rightarrow x \neq-\frac{1}{2} \\
& \frac{|2-5 x|}{|2 x+1|} \leq 2,|2-5 x|=\left\{\begin{array}{c}
2-5 x, 2-5 x \geq 0, x \leq \frac{2}{5} \\
-(2-5 x), 2-5 x<0, x>\frac{2}{5}
\end{array}\right\},|2 x+1|=\left\{\begin{array}{c}
2 x+1,2 x+1>0, x>-\frac{1}{2} \\
-(2 x+1), 2 x+1<0, x<-\frac{1}{2}
\end{array}\right\} \\
& I: x \in\left(-\infty,-\frac{1}{2}\right) \\
& \frac{2-5 x}{-(2 x+1)}-2 \leq 0 \Rightarrow \frac{5 x-2}{2 x+1}-2 \leq 0 \Rightarrow \frac{x-4}{2 x+1} \leq 0 \Rightarrow x \in\left(-\frac{1}{2}, 4\right] \cap I \Rightarrow x \in\{\varnothing\} \text {. } \\
&
\end{aligned}
$$
No integer solutions
$$
\begin{aligned}
& I I: x \in\left(-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{2}{5}\right] \\
& \frac{2-5 x}{2 x+1}-2 \leq 0 \Rightarrow \frac{5 x-2}{2 x+1}+2 \geq 0 \Rightarrow \frac{9 x}{2 x+1} \geq 0 \Rightarrow x \in\left(-\infty,-\frac{1}{2}\right) \cup[0,+\infty) \cap I I \Rightarrow x \in\left[0, \frac{2}{5}\right) .
\end{aligned}
$$
Integer solution $: x_1=0$.
$$
\begin{aligned}
& I I I: x \in\left(\frac{2}{5},+\infty\right) \\
& \frac{-(2-5 x)}{2 x+1}-2 \leq 0 \Rightarrow \frac{5 x-2}{2 x+1}-2 \leq 0 \Rightarrow \frac{x-4}{2 x+1} \leq 0 \Rightarrow x \in\left(-\frac{1}{2}, 4\right] \cap I I \Rightarrow \Rightarrow x \in\left(\frac{2}{5}, 4\right] .
\end{aligned}
$$
Integer solutions: $x_2=1, x_3=2, x_4=3, x_5=4$.
Number of integer solutions is 5.

**Second:**
Image(in final answer there is a typo, it is not (0,4] but [0, 4]): [image]

Comment: Why did you reject 0 at the very end? Or is that a typo and you meant $X \in [0, 4]$?

Comment: Oh it is a typo, i just noticed it, thank u.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is correct (After fixing the final step to $ x \in [ 0, 4 ] $).

Note that in the first solution, for case II, the conclusion should be $ x \in [ 0, \frac{2}{5} \color{red}{]}$. I'm guessing this is just a typo.
With that, both solution ranges match, are equal to $ x \in [ 0, 4 ]$, which give the same integer solutions.

Side note: My favorite way of dealing with these types of absolute value inequalities (single term only) is just to square and multiply out the denominator (excluding when it is 0) to obtain $ (2 - 5x) ^2 \leq 2^2 (2x+1)^2$, which we can easily shift over and factorize to $(2 - 5x - 2(2x+1) ) ( 2 - 5x+2(2x+1) ) \leq 0 $, and hence arrive at $ x \in [ 0, 4 ]$. It is quick, easy to follow, and avoids a lot of potential computational errors.